# How to restrict a function call multiple time

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code.

`<a href="javascript:objectView('3','1215')">Raja</a>`

if i click on the link 'Raja' multiple time `objectview()` function call multiple time.
i want to restrict multiple function call.

how to restrict multiple call.
if you have any idea share with me.

Comment: What do you mean by *restrict*? Only allow the function to be called once?

Comment: set this.onClick = null; OR this.onClick="javascript:void(0);"; at the end of your objectView() function.. Or use a gloabl level variable to check whether to execute internal logic of function or not

Answer (score 2):

you can  do that by jquery [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/).. but since you are calling inline function (making it as simple as i can)

try this

```
var clicked=false;
function objectView(obj1,obj2){
  if(!clicked){
     //your code
    clicked=true;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this-

```
$('#rajaLink').click(function(){
  objectView('3','1215');
  $('#rajaLink').unbind('click'); // Unbind event
});
```